# Как сделать работу Telegram бота изолированной

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, state, global-variables

Написал простого Telegram бота для генерации случайных чисел. По умолчанию, при первом запуске по команде /start задумывалось, что диапазон чисел для генерации чисел будет от 1 до 100, значения 1 и 100 хранятся в отдельных глобальных переменных. Сделал команду /range, чтобы можно было установить свой собственный диапазон чисел. Использовал для команды /range state'ы, после чего введённые от пользователя значения записывал в глобальные переменные и использовал эти глобальные переменные в обработчике команды /generate - сгенерировать число.

Проблема такая: если один пользователь использовал команду /range, изменил диапазон, то этот диапазон изменится у всех пользователей Telegram. Также если кем-то уже установлен диапазон, то при первом запуске будет использоваться как раз таки этот диапазон, а не от 1 до 100 по умолчанию.

Думаю, что это всё из-за глобальных переменных и state'ов.

Я начинающий в этом плане, и это моя первая работа с aiogram. Читал документацию, но так ничего и не дошло. Буду рад любой помощи.

```py
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.utils import executor
import random

# bot token
API_TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# default range from 0 to 100
num_from = 0
num_to = 100

# Set range of numbers from user in states
class numbersForm(StatesGroup):
    number_from = State()
    number_to = State()

# /start command
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Я бот-генератор случайных чисел\nДиапазон чисел по умолчанию: от 1 до 100\nМои команды:\n/language - Выбрать язык.\n/range - Задать свой диапазон чисел.\n/generate - Сгенерировать число")

# /range command
@dp.message_handler(commands=['range'])
async def choose_range(message: types.Message):
    global language
    await numbersForm.number_from.set()
    await message.answer("Введите начальное число: ", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

# handler for number_from
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.isdigit(), state=numbersForm.number_from)
async def process_number_from(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global language
    await numbersForm.next()
    await state.update_data(number_from=int(message.text))
    await message.answer("Введите конечное число: ")

# handler for number_to
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.isdigit(), state=numbersForm.number_to)
async def process_number_to(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global num_to
    global num_from
    global language
    await numbersForm.next()
    await state.update_data(number_to=int(message.text))
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        await message.answer(md.text('Ваш диапазон чисел установлен: ', 'от ', data['number_from'], ' до ', data['number_to']))
        await message.answer("Введите команду /generate, чтобы сгененрировать число")
        # set numbers from user to global variables
        num_from = int(md.text(data['number_from']))
        num_to = int(md.text(data['number_to'])) + 1
    await state.finish()

# /generate command
@dp.message_handler(commands=['generate'])
async def generate(message: types.Message):
    global language
    global num_to
    global num_from
    try:
        global num_to
        global num_from
        generated_number = random.randrange(num_from, num_to)
        await message.answer("Ваше число: " + str(generated_number))
    except ValueError:
        await message.answer("Вы ввели неправильный диапазон чисел\nВозможно начальное число больше конечного\nИспользуйте команду /range, чтобы задать числовой диапазон")
        

# handler for other messages
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Я не знаю, как вам ответить\nЧтобы узнать больше информации, введите команду /start")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну штош. Во первых избавьтесь от

```
# default range from 0 to 100
num_from = 0
num_to = 100
```

Дальше хранить эти данные можно двумя путями.

Первый делать БД, где будет по юзер айди храниться и язык и рендж и все что вам понадобиться.

Второй хранить в FSM данные не удаляя их. То есть не юзая state.finish и state.reset_state с параметром with_data=True. Короче небольшой гемор но в целом можно жить. Ну и просто к этому пункту скажу, что мемори данные держит до первого отключения сервера бота и вам придется юзать redis или mongoDB чтобы они хоть где-то хранились.

Расписывать первый я не буду, но вот второй дам.

```
# Set range of numbers from user in states
class NumbersForm(StatesGroup):
    number_from = State()
    number_to = State()


# /start command
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number_from'] = 0
        data['number_to'] = 100

    await message.answer(
        "Я бот-генератор случайных чисел\n"
        "Диапазон чисел по умолчанию: от 1 до 100\n"
        "Мои команды:\n"
        "/language - Выбрать язык.\n"
        "/range - Задать свой диапазон чисел.\n"
        "/generate - Сгенерировать число")


# /range command
@dp.message_handler(commands=['range'])
async def choose_range(message: types.Message):
    await NumbersForm.number_from.set()
    await message.answer("Введите начальное число: ", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())


# handler for number_from
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.isdigit(), state=NumbersForm.number_from)
async def process_number_from(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await NumbersForm.next()
    await state.update_data(number_from=int(message.text))
    await message.answer("Введите конечное число: ")


# handler for number_to
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.isdigit(), state=NumbersForm.number_to)
async def process_number_to(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await NumbersForm.next()

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number_to'] = int(message.text)
        await message.answer(md.text(
            f'Ваш диапазон чисел установлен: от {data["number_from"]} до {data["number_to"]}'
            f'Введите команду /generate, чтобы сгененрировать число'))
    await state.reset_state(with_data=False)


# /generate command
@dp.message_handler(commands=['generate'])
async def generate(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        num_from = data['number_from']
        num_to = data['number_to']
    try:
        generated_number = random.randrange(num_from, num_to)
        await message.answer("Ваше число: " + str(generated_number))
    except ValueError:
        await message.answer(
            "Вы ввели неправильный диапазон чисел\n"
            "Возможно начальное число больше конечного\n"
            "Используйте команду /range, чтобы задать числовой диапазон")


# handler for other messages
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Я не знаю, как вам ответить\nЧтобы узнать больше информации, введите команду /start")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, что-то получается. Попробую ещё вариант с базой данных допилить.